# Destructuring ES6 Nested Objects

Tags: javascript

How can I use ES6 with Destructuring to provide options to users. Not sure how to use nested objects without getting the defaults overwritten by partial objects.

[Take this simple example from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#ES6_version):

```html
function drawES6Chart({size = 'big', cords = { x: 0, y: 0 }, radius = 25} = {})
{
  console.log(size, cords, radius);
  // do some chart drawing
}

drawES6Chart({
  cords: { x: 18},
  radius: 30
});
```

The output shows

```
big {"x":18} 30
```

but I want it to show

```
big {"x":18,"y": 0} 30
```

The provided cords object is partial and removes the default y value. I want to keep any value that is not explicitly overwritten.

Comment: This has nothing to do with ES6's "classes." It has to do with ES6's *default arguments*.

Comment: Not sure you can let the interpreter know the nested object should be destructured too. `;{let {x = 0, y = 0} = cords; cords = {x: x, y: y}};` ?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to destructure the `coords` into its `x` an `y` components and provide default values for them separately:

```
function drawES6Chart({size='big', cords: {x=0, y=0} = {}, radius=25} = {}) {
    const coords = {x, y}
    console.log(size, coords, radius);
}
```

The way you had written it would only provide a default value if no `cords` object was provided at all.
You already had chosen the correct approach for the complete options objects, which has the `{}` as its default value as well - instead of writing

```
function drawES6Chart({size, cords, radius} = {size:'big', cords:{x:0, y:0}, radius:25}) {
    // not working
```

Comment: I thought I *tried* that! *sigh* Bedtime... *Edit:* Ah, no, not *quite* that. But that's much cleaner than the `Object.assign` approach.

Comment: I really like this with the exception that it will initialise the identifiers _x_ and _y_. This is what I tried to avoid with the weird code-block-`let`.

Comment: @PaulS.: Yes, that's a difference from the original code, but I don't think there's anything wrong with it. Two variables that might be used anyway are hardly harmful, are they?

Answer (score 1):

You can supply defaults for the overall options object (as you are), but not (directly) for subordinate objects in it.

I like [bergi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33336387/157247), but [as Paul pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33336170/destructuring-es6-nested-objects#comment54469716_33336387), it does define the `x` and `y` symbols within the function.

If you don't want that, you can use `Object.assign` within the function instead:

```
cords = Object.assign({}, {x: 0, y:0}, cords);
```

Feels ES5-ish, but...

To avoid repeating yourself, you can put the defaults in a variable: ([live copy on Babel's REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=let%20cordsDefaults%20%3D%20%7Bx%3A%200%2C%20y%3A%200%7D%3B%0Afunction%20drawES6Chart(%0A%20%20%7Bsize%20%3D%20'big'%2C%20cords%20%3D%20cordsDefaults%2C%20radius%20%3D%2025%7D%20%3D%20%7B%7D%0A%20%20)%0A%7B%0A%20%20cords%20%3D%20Object.assign(%7B%7D%2C%20cordsDefaults%2C%20cords)%3B%0A%20%20console.log(size%2C%20cords%2C%20radius)%3B%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20do%20some%20chart%20drawing%0A%7D%0AdrawES6Chart(%7Bcords%3A%20%7Bx%3A18%7D%7D)%3B))

```
let cordsDefaults = {x: 0, y: 0};
function drawES6Chart(
  {size = 'big', cords = cordsDefaults, radius = 25} = {}
  )
{
  cords = Object.assign({}, cordsDefaults, cords);
  console.log(size, cords, radius);
  // do some chart drawing
}
drawES6Chart({cords: {x:18}});
```

Output:

```
big {"x":18,"y":0} 25
```

Comment: This worked absolutely perfectly.  Object assign was key and the default object made things much less verbose.  Thank you!

Comment: @JeremyBYU - Therefore shouldn't you mark the answer as correct??